# Simple way to get a unload of group of tables in a text file in Oracle 9i

Tags: sql, oracle9i

I need to get unload of group of tables in oracle 9i.
The unload should be a `.txt` file or `.unl` file.
I have googled and found that the script specifying the column names of the table.
As I have huge number columns in the tables, I don't want to specify column names while taking unload. Anybody can please give me a simple solution to take unload without using column names.

Comment: I got the answer for the above question.`exp USERID=username/password TABLES=username.tablename FILE=tablename.dmp` This will export all the data in tablename.dmp file. We can import the same data to the table using `imp USERID=username/password FILE=tablename.dmp ignore=Y FULL=Y`

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to specify the column names?

```
./sqlldr_exp user/passdword@instance >  emp.ctl
```

No column names explicitly required.

Do you mean you don't even want the columns mentioned in the loader file? It is my understanding that would not be possible: you will need to allow oracle to place the columns. Similar to views using select * from some_table: the columns actually become  materialized so that if the underlying columns change the view has to be recreated.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I got the answer.`exp USERID=username/password TABLES=username.tablename FILE=tablename.dmp` This will export all the data in tablename.dmp file. We can import the same data to the table using `imp USERID=username/password FILE=tablename.dmp ignore=Y FULL=Y`